# Known examples of complete homogeneous quadratic systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in systems of the form:

$\frac{d}{dt}(x) = Q(x,x)$

where $x: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map from an open interval $I$ containing $0$, and $Q(-,-): \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a symmetric bilinear map with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

More specifically, a generic such system is known to have at least one initial point for which the integral curve goes to infinity in finite time (possibly in the past, or in the future, we shall not make a distinction between these two cases).

But I am interested in examples of such systems, for which the integral curves exist for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, I am interested in such systems for which one never has a finite time blow-up, no matter what the initial condition is.

Can someone suggest a reference containing all known examples of such systems (for which there is no finite time blow-up) please?